# Electric field at a point created by a charged object (derivation/integration process)

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, integration, mathematics, calculus

I was hoping someone can help me understand the math behind the electric field (electrostatics). I have gaps in my knowledge about integrals and derivatives (university moves very quickly and it has been years since high school) so I'm hoping someone can help me intuitively understand the math so I know how and when to apply it.

Consider this, where we have a charged rod of length L, and I want to find the total electric field at that point to the right of it.
What I understand so far is that if I want to find the total electric field at that point, I need to find all the contributions to the electric field from every point in the rod.
So I first consider how much electric field E is produced by a portion of q.

We know by the definition for the electric field created by a point charge is: $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}) = \frac{kq}{r^2} \mathbf{\hat{r}}$
Since $E$ represents the total electric field, we want to know dE which is the infinitisimally small amount of electric field created by an infinitisimal amount of charge dq.

**My first question:** The k and the r are constants in this situation, correct? Because they are constant for the dq of interest?

[image]

So now because we are interested in the total electric field, we want to integrate dE.

**My second question:** But what I don't really understand is what are we integrating it with respect to?

What I have been told is: $\lambda = q/l$, $q = \lambda l$, so $dq = \lambda dl$

Hence we get $\int \mathbf{dE} = \int \frac{k \lambda dl}{r^2}$.
Then the bounds of the integral are from D (one end of the rod) to D+L (the other end of the rod).

I'm just quite confused on the whole derivative to integral process. Especially since I then need to understand this situation where it's a curved rod and I'm trying to find the electric field at that centre point:

[image]

Comment: *The k and the r are constants in this situation, correct? Because they are constant for the dq of interest?* The distance $r$ is the distance from an element of charge $dq$ to the point where you are computing the field. Thus in general it varies for the different elements of charge that you are integrating over. There is no useful sense in which $r$ is a constant for the straight rod. In particular, it is not a constant in the integral, and so can’t come out of the integral like $k$ does. For a circular rod, it is constant only if you are calculating the field at the center.

Comment: $\int \mathbf{dE} = \int \frac{k \lambda dl}{r^2}$ doesn’t make sense as an equation because the left side is a vector and the right side isn’t.

Answer (score 0):

It is often the case that the electric field is found by integrating Coulomb's law:
$$\vec E(\vec r)=k{q\over |\vec r-\vec r^\prime|^3}(\vec r-\vec r^\prime).$$ As you note in your post, we can write the field for an infinitesimal element:
$$d\vec E=k{dq\over |\vec r-\vec r^\prime|^3}(\vec r-\vec r^\prime).$$
That is, an infinitesimal element of the field corresponds to an infinitesimal element of the charge or source of the field. Now, for any distribution of charge $\rho(\vec r)$, we have by definition of charge density that:
$$\rho={d\rho\over dV}.$$
If the density is not a three-dimensional distribution, then the derivative will be with respect to area for a two-dimensional distribution:
$$\rho={d\rho\over dA},$$
or for a 1-dimensional distribution, with respect to length:
$$\rho={d\rho\over dl}.$$
So, for the problem in your post concerning the line of charge, we can write an infinitesimal element of charge $dq$, as $dq=\rho\;dl$. Thus, we can integrate over the length of the charge distribution, this is how the limits of integration are set. So you get:
$$\vec E=\int \; d\vec E=\int k{dq\over |\vec r-\vec r^\prime|^3}(\vec r-\vec r^\prime)=\int_D^{D+L} k{\rho\;dl\over|\vec r-\vec r^\prime|^3}(\vec r-\vec r^\prime).$$
Now, let us determine the vector $\vec r-\vec r^\prime$, for the geometry in the problem we have:
$$\vec r-\vec r^\prime=(x-x^\prime)\mathbf{\hat i}$$
and,
$$|\vec r-\vec r^\prime|^3=(x-x^\prime)^{3/2}.$$
Substituting these into the integral we get:
$$\vec E(x)=\int_D^{D+L}k\rho{(x-x^\prime)\over(x-x^\prime)^{3/2}}\mathbf{\hat i}\; dx^\prime.$$
Thus, once one has determined the form of the $d\vec E$ from the geometry of the problem, it is left to simply perform the integration to find the field.

Comment: $\rho=d\rho/dV$ should be $\rho=dq/dV$. Etc.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation about the definition of charge density, that is very helpful. One thing I'm a bit confused about is how did you get $r^3$ ? I have that Coulomb's law is $r^2$

Comment: @1899DVX $(\vec{r}-\vec{r}^\prime)/|\vec{r}-\vec{r}^\prime|$ is a unit vector, its norm (length) is $1$.